# I Need more contact base types

Tags: contacts

I need to add to my CRM object which are neither Individual/Household/Organization.
In my case an example would be embryos which relate to their parents (yes, in fertilization process) which have many attributes but none of the individual's (they don't have names/phone/address/skype etc).

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You might consider not making those into contacts.  Instead, set up a set of custom fields on an individual (parent) or household that allows for multiple entries (in a tab).  You can then record the necessary information without cluttering your CRM with contacts who have no names and can't be contacted.

Comment: this might help in certain occasions, but in my case those entities have too many relations. An embryo relates to genetic father (contact in CRM), genetic mother (contact as well), Parents (not necessarily genetic), clinic (contact) and actions should be deployed on it (just as on any other contact in CRM).

I thought maybe use Drupal's entities and relations (create new bundles) but not sure how well it will work with civi.

Comment: You could use contact reference custom fields in that custom field set to record all those various contacts.  It won't appear on the other contacts' records, but if that becomes the sticking point, you could use one of a bunch of ways to display that.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to create a sub-type of "Individual" and use a hook to remove options from the create/edit form. This is probably not as good as Andrew's proposed solution but wanted to include it for completeness.